# Get response from blob

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the response from a service call which returns a blob for a pdf.  I have made the call but am not sure how to subscribe to it. Here is my code

service.ts

```
  openDoc(val) {
    const token = this._storeService.getStoredData().access_token;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
      .set('observe', 'response')
      .set('responseType', 'blob');
    const options = { headers: headers };
    const url = val;
    return this._http.get<any>(url, options);
  }
```

component.ts

//my attempt at get the blob

```
openDocWindow(url: string) {
    this._candidateService.openDoc(url).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("response"+ res);
      this.currentDocumentUrl = res;
      this.showDocumentWindow = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: whats your response for the invocation

Comment: @SasiKumarM I get this %PDF-1.4
%Ã¤Ã¼Ã¶Ã.......